# mirth file reader to read fhir-json content and replace few string

Tags: filereader, filewriter, hl7-fhir, mirth

I want read file through mirth file reader which has fHIR-Json. I need to replace the string values and again write it in to the same file. How to do that.

e.g

`{"resourceType":"Bundle","id":"66bebc03-3480-4278-9f26-f9fd72478dcd","type":"searchset",`

I want to replace "resourceType" : "Patient" "type":"transaction" all other contents are same And write it to the same file.

After writing the file I have post it to another fhir server.

when I tried to read file its give me error

> SyntaxError: Expected end of stream at char 33880

So far I couldnt solve it.

Comment: I cannot provide help on Mirth. However: you cannot replace the Bundle resource type with Patient and then set the type to transaction. You will not have a valid Patient resource. Keep Bundle, because that can hold a transaction. But also you will have to add details for each entry if you want the Bundle to function as a transaction correctly when sending to the other FHIR server.